# Independence of real variables

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, independence

I have a set based definition of independence ($P(X\in A, Y \in B) = P(X\in A)P(Y\in B)$), and I have to prove the following assertion:

Let $X_1,\dots,X_n$ be real-valued random variables. Show that $X_1,\dots,X_n$ are jointly independent if and only if one has
$$\displaystyle {\bf P}\left( \bigwedge_{i=1}^n (X_i \leq t_i) \right) = \prod_{i=1}^n {\bf P}( X_i \leq t_i )$$
for all $t_1,\dots,t_n \in {\bf R}$.

Unfortunately, after much effort, I do not even know where to start.

Comment: $\Rightarrow$ is an easy induction from the definition of independence.  For $\Leftarrow$, how far down the sigma-algebra rabbit hole do you want to go?

Comment: @Henry all the way down, as deep as it goes

Comment: Ok, I figured it out: I should have looked at the generating Boolean algebras and how they interact with measurable functions..